# Prove the Binomial Theorem for negative integral index by induction using a Caucy product.

Tags: real-analysis

In other words, give a power series which converges to $\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^n}$ when $-1<x<1$.

I am pretty confused by this question in first place and second one is when viewing the solution for it.I don't really understand it. Need an Intutive approach for both question and Proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the power series for $1/(1-x)^n$. So you want the coefficients $a_j$ such that
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^n} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j \quad \forall x \in (-1,1).
$$

By "using a Cauchy product" I believe you have to use the binomial formula
$$(1-x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {n\choose k} x^k,
$$ where I'm considering ${n\choose k}=0$ for $k>n$,
and the identity
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^n} (1-x)^n =1
$$
in order to find the coefficients $a_j$ using the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) .

So we have
\begin{align*}
1&=\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}(1-x)^n 
\\&= \big(\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j \big)\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {n\choose k} x^k\bigg)
\\& \sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^ka_j {n \choose k} x^{j+k}.
\end{align*}

Since
$$1=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^ka_j {n \choose k} x^{j+k},
$$
we have

\begin{align*}
1&=a_0
\\0&=  \sum_{k+j=1} (-1)^k {n \choose k} a_j = a_1-{n \choose 1}a_0
\\0&=  \sum_{k+j=2} (-1)^k {n \choose k} a_j = a_2-{n \choose 1}a_1+{n \choose 2}a_0
\\& \cdots
\\ 0&=  \sum_{k+j=i} (-1)^k {n \choose k} a_j
\\& \cdots
\end{align*}

Using the above equations you can explicitly find the coefficients $a_j$.

Comment: @RealDumbfoggybrain Note that $\binom{n}{k}=0$ only for $k>n$. We have $$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}.$$

Comment: Exactly. The number ${n \choose k}$ is usually defined by the formula
$${n \choose k} =\frac{ n(n-1)\cdots(n-(k+1))}{k!}.
$$
This formula makes sense for all non-negative integers $n$ and $k$. In the case $k>n$ we have one of the terms in the product $n(n-1)\cdots(n-(k+1))$ is zero and therefore ${n \choose k}=0$.

Comment: Sorry for too much trouble . Now I know how to prove it. I apologize you guys for being too lazy to use my mind. I figured out that the coefficients are ((n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+r))/r!.

Comment: ((n+1)(n+2)...(n+r))/k! this question was trivial. One again I apologies for my foggy brain asking this question and wasting your time.